# Loggin REST request/response in database

Tags: rest, logging, jaxb, cxf

I would like to log REST request and reponse of my applications that use CXF and JAXB.

I used to log the unmarshalled objects before calling the webservice using AOP and then I switched to cxf interceptors but i'm not very confortable with the PHASE concepts of cxf interceptors (poor documentation).

That's why I would like to know if there are better ways to log the XML request and response of a REST webservice (with some additional information in my table).

I'm using JDK 5 and tomcat 5 (yeah I know...)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the CXF docs that covers some of this:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html

More specifically, you could subclass the CXF logging interceptors and override the one method they have for actually doing the logging.